# Xcode 14 Asset validation failed - missing app icon

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, assets, appicon

after long nights of programming, I have finally finished my app and would now like to upload it to the AppStore Connect for testing purposes, but I always get the same 2 error messages because of certain sizes of the app icon are missing (screenshot attached). I have tried pretty much everything from Stackoverflow, but nothing helped or a lot of things are already out of date, because in Xcode 14 you can only specify one size for the app icon (1.024px x 1.024px).

Does anyone here have a solution for this problem?

The "AppIcon" is in the `Assets.xcassets` folder & I added some attributes in the `info.plist` file to eliminate some other error messages. (Do I have to add my App as a target in the info.plist file, because I get some errors when I do?)

**AppIcon in Assets folder**
[AppIcon in Assets folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4BMH.png)

**Info.plist file**
[Info.plist File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFETJ.png)

**Error messages**
[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrvX3.png)

Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow so I can't post images directly.

Comment: What is your deployment target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long and hair-raising moments I figured it out now. My `Assets.xcassets` folder was inside another folder in my project. I dragged the Assets folder to the root were also the `info.plist` file is and my upload worked.

Answer (score 3):

From [Xcode 14 Release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes):

> Apps using a single-size app icon can fail App Store validation if the deployment target is older than iOS 12 or watchOS 4. (98471456)

So, I would guess this is a bug caused by old deployment target.

Comment: Oh okay thanks, is there any possible solution for that yet?

Comment: The thing is my minimum deployment target is iOS15 and it still fails

Comment: @SCH361 Is your asset file properly added to your project?

Comment: yes it is - I added it about 15 times now